# Select Database name from another Database

Tags: mysql

I have a DB where several Tables are stored like "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" etc. and one Table called "Items".

In "Items" there are all names so you know what sort of values are in the Tables "Item1", "Item2" etc..

Now I like to Select the data from eg. Table "Item2" where all Inside Temperatures  are stored. However I like to acces them via the **Items** table where the ID is stored of the Item Table. See Table Items. The ID for "Temperature Inside" is 2 so I like to get the data from table **Item2**

So something like this:

```
SELECT Value AS "Test"
FROM (SELECT concat('Item', ItemId) FROM Items WHERE ItemName = "Temperature Inside")
```

Table **Item2**:

```
time   Value
............
1      58               
2      67              
3      25 
6      1
```

Table **Items**:

```
ItemId    ItemName 
......................
1         "Temperature Outside"
2         "Temperature Inside"              
3         "Power"             
4         "Voltage"
```

Comment: Sorry but what you are trying to say?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join/6188334#6188334

Comment: but join works only if I know the name of both tables but I don't know it since the name of table I like to use is stored in the "Items" table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use the below query. You have to use dynamic SQL to generate your `select` query. First get the `id` from items table and create your select query using `concat`. Finally using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` you can get the required output.

```
select @var :=itemid from items where itemname='Temperature Inside';
set @sqltext := concat('select * from item',@var);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sqltext;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[**Check DEMO Here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=32200b57828a32f21f50b533cb35af3a)